Nodemailer SMTP auth cliendId, privateKey using google application default serviceAccount
Is there a way to retrieve clientId and privateKey for the OAuth nodemailer from the google application default instead of getting it from the service key json file?
Since applicationDefault doesn't have clientId, how should I proceed?
smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: provider.auth.user,
      pass: provider.auth.pass,
      serviceClient: '//clientId',
      privateKey: '//privateKey',
    },
  } as SMTPTransport.Options);

I created a new OAuth clientId and use it's clientId and clientSecret but it's still not working...
smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: provider.auth.user,
        clientId: '//clientId',
        clientSecret: '//clientSecret',
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    } as SMTPTransport.Options);

Email can be sent if I'm using the user created service account cliendId and privateKey.
I have checked the permissions for the application default service account role comparing to that working user created service account...
